# website to activate my python scraper using c# and possibly a raspberry pi

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, django, raspberry-pi3

I am interested in making a website that activates a python script. I am most familiar with c# but I have a python scraping script I would like to use that currently runs well on my raspberry pi.

My question is:

How do I make a C# asp.net website that activates the python script? what is the best approach? should i just forget c# all together and use something like django to host the site?

Answer (score 0):

Considering how easy that is with something like django, I would go that route. Unless you're a C# wizard (I am most certainly not) or need it for something else.

Comment: so i would need to download django on raspberry pi and create a website using the django templates etc.. then i could host the site on Google App Engine and activate the scraper that way?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the Google app engine, but giving it a quick google it looks like you could do that. I hosted my last django project with apache, required a relatively small amount of configuration. Also, depending on what you're trying to do, your django templates could be very simple.